# Knockoutjs and setting up view model

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, knockout.js

I have in my view model an `observable` object with an array and I want to populate it with different items, item1, item2, each item with its' own setup. So I am trying to figure out the best way to set this up.

My Current setup is bad, there are still some bugs that I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

For example, I create an item1 and then Save, I then try to create another item1 and when the popup pops up the input fields are filled out with the values from the first item1 I created, I don't know why because I reset the variables after I save.

I am just wondering if I am doing this correct or not, what can I do to make it better.

Please look at my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lhalverson/m3vzLw2p/)**

I did shrink my Item1 but keep in mind that I have 10+ variables to it.

Also I do know that Item1 and Item2 are setup differently, I was just testing what would be the best way to go about this, knowing I have objects with 10+ vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small change will do the trick . Make `item1Setup` as observable rather simple  JavaScript variable which don't react to changes i.e something like`self.item1Setup=ko.observable()`

**viewModel:**

```
var myViewModel = function() {
    var itemData = ko.observable({
        "data": []
    });
    var self=this;
    self.item1Setup = ko.observable(); //declare it here

    //Create Item1 Popup
    self.item1Setup(new item1("", 0, "")); // assign instance to observable

    function createItem1() {
        self.item1Setup().item1Id(getNewId()); // assign value to observable content
        itemData().data.push(self.item1Setup());
        shouldShowPopup(false, "Item1");
        //reset back to defaults
        resetVariables("Item1");
    }

    function resetVariables(resetType) {
        switch (resetType) {
            case "Item1":
                self.item1Setup(new item1("", 0, "")); //you can reset as it is observable UI takes it changes
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    return {
        itemData: itemData,
        item2Id: item2Id,
        item2Title: item2Title,  
        item2Location: item2Location,
        item1Setup: self.item1Setup, //return observable 
        addItem2: addItem2,
        createItem1: createItem1,
        editItem1: editItem1,
        getItem1FromList: getItem1FromList,
        resetVariables: resetVariables
    }
}
```

I cropped up some code to explain pivotal issue check the working fiddle **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/m3vzLw2p/19/)** for createitem1 .

Comment: Fantastic! Can't believe I didn't do that in the first place! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Several ways you could make this better:

1. Use Knockout's click bindings for your buttons
2. Create a [custom binding handler](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html) to control modal visibility with an observable boolean (each modal gets its own variable, they all use the same binding type)
3. Make your items their own objects; don't have variables prefixed with item2, etc.
4. Don't have things like `resetVariables` that have to figure out which item type you're working with, have the items know how to reset themselves

Comment: Perfect now that my problem got solved I will defiantly make some changes! Thanks for the good tips!